# wifi channel graph is showing in lollipop but not in marshmallow android

Tags: android

public class ChannelGraphFragment extends Fragment {
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_content, container, false);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.graphRefresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new ListViewOnRefreshListener());

    Configuration configuration = MainContext.INSTANCE.getConfiguration();
    ChannelGraphNavigation channelGraphNavigation = new ChannelGraphNavigation(getActivity(), configuration);
    ChannelGraphAdapter channelGraphAdapter = new ChannelGraphAdapter(channelGraphNavigation);
    addGraphViews(swipeRefreshLayout, channelGraphAdapter);
    addGraphNavigation(view, channelGraphNavigation);

    return view;
}

private void addGraphNavigation(View view, ChannelGraphNavigation channelGraphNavigation) {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.graphNavigation);
    for (NavigationItem navigationItem : channelGraphNavigation.getNavigationItems()) {
        linearLayout.addView(navigationItem.getButton());
    }
}

private void addGraphViews(View view, ChannelGraphAdapter channelGraphAdapter) {
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) view.findViewById(R.id.graphFlipper);
    for (GraphView graphView : channelGraphAdapter.getGraphViews()) {
        viewFlipper.addView(graphView);
    }
}

private void refresh() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    Scanner scanner = MainContext.INSTANCE.getScanner();
    scanner.update();
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refresh();
}

private class ListViewOnRefreshListener implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        refresh();
    }
}
```

above is my code

pls help me.
it run successfully on lollipop and also run if i do not use firebase in my app. when i add firebase database, it does not show graph in marshmallow